# how to write XPath of a nested element

Tags: html, xpath

HTML structure is as shown below,

```
<div class  = "items">
   <oj-input-text class = "input", label-hint = "asd">
       <input class = "text-input-entry">
   <oj-input-text class = "input", label-hint = "pfg">
       <input class = "text-input-entry">
```

How do I write Xpath to get to input class = "text-input-entry" under oj-input-text class = "input", for the label-hint = "pfg"

I thought something like this would work but it does not

```
//div [@class = "items"]/oj-input-text [@class = "input", @label-hint = "pfg"]/input [@class = "text-input-entry"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting your description to XPath is strait-forward.
It will be:

```py
//oj-input-text[@class = 'input' and @label-hint = 'pfg']//input[@class = 'text-input-entry']
```

or in case if `oj-input-text` is not a regular element tag name as it looks here

```py
//*[name()=oj-input-text and @class = 'input' and @label-hint = 'pfg']//input[@class = 'text-input-entry']
```

`//oj-input-text[@class = 'input' and @label-hint = 'pfg']//input[@class = 'text-input-entry']` means as following:
`//` somewhere on the document
`oj-input-text` node with `oj-input-text` tag name
`@class = 'input'` element `class` attribute value is `input`
`and` - another condition there
`@label-hint = 'pfg'` - `label-hint` attribute has value of `pgf`
second `//` - somewhere below this element, inside it
`input` - tag name `input`
`class = 'text-input-entry'` - `class` attribute with value of `text-input-entry`

Answer (score 1):

Use Chrome DevTools -> Inspect -> Copy -> Copy XPath
This will give you an example of how to build the XPath.
i.e. The XPath of your question's code: `//*[@id="question"]/div/div[2]/div[1]/pre[1]/code`

Comment: Is there an equivalent in Firefox, my site is private and works on Firefox only

Comment: Yes, there is. Open the Firefox Web Developer Tools with `f12` select Inspector tab, select your element, right click, copy -> XPath

Comment: @MadsHansen using automatically created xpath is not a good solution in most times.

Comment: For sure, not always the best or most optimal. The question was whether Firefox has the same capability as Chrome (it does). And those auto-generated XPath can convenient starting points and further refined, but save some keystrokes and an okay starting point for those unfamiliar with XPath.

Comment: Ok, here i agree with you :)