# Get specific occurrence Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am automating a website, and it has multiple searchboxes with the same title, class, etc. It usually occurs 2 or 3 times on every page. Is there a way in which I can tell Selenium to only use the 2nd or 3rd occurrence?

I currently have this:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, './/*[@title = "Searchbox"]').click()
```

And

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, './/*[@title = "Searchbox"]').send_keys(i)
```

It currently clicks the first searchbox and types number i, but I want Selenium to do this for any other searchbox with the same html.

Thanks!

Comment: So there will always be something uniques about each searchbox, maybe 'label-hint', or 'text' etc. Once you find that out you will have to write custom XPaths to access them and perform the required actions.

Comment: Refer this to find out how to write custom Xpaths => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70776928/how-to-write-xpath-of-a-nested-element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally your [locator strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890) should identify each and every [WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52782684/what-is-the-difference-between-webdriver-and-webelement-in-selenium/52805139#52805139) uniquely within the [DOM Tree](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes).

As your [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48054321/of-the-many-findelements-by-functions-in-selenium-when-would-you-use-one-over/48056120#48056120) identifies 2 or 3 elements on every page, you need to construct a more canonical locator. However the following line of code:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, './/*[@title = "Searchbox"]')
```

will always select the ***first*** matching element.

---

To click on the *second* and *third* matching element, you can use the following *locator strategies*:

- To click on second match:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "(.//*[@title = "Searchbox"])[1]").click()
  ```
- To click on third:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "(.//*[@title = "Searchbox"])[2]").click()
  ```

Comment: Thanks! I understand your logic, but you removed both of the ‘ at the beginning and and, and replace them by brackets. If I do this, I get the SyntaxError, and if I use them combined I get InvalidSelectorException. Do you know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: @Not_a_Robot Missed the double quotes, added now. Let me know the status.

Answer (score 0):

As a last resort you can use xpath indexing:

if this `.//*[@title = "Searchbox"]` represent `1/3 nodes` or `1/2 nodes`

you can simply change it to

```
(.//*[@title = "Searchbox"])[2]
```

and use it like this:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "(.//*[@title = 'Searchbox'])[2]").send_keys(i)
```

to represent **2nd node**

or **[3]** to represent 3rd node.

```
(.//*[@title = "Searchbox"])[3]
```

and so on....

This is not recommended but can be used as a last resort.

Answer (score 0):

To get some element by it's occurrence using xpath just wrap the xpath in `(<your xpath>)[number]` where `number` is the element occurrence number.

For click the second one:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '(.//*[@title = "Searchbox"])[2]').click()
```

Comment: after 5 hours you have given the same answer which is already answered by 2 answerers. What addition does it add to the community?

Comment: @cruisepandey If still no any answer is accepted, they might be unclear to the person who asked. I've rephrased the answer in the way, how I think it's more clear. Is such behavior is a bad practice? No issue, I'll able to delete this answer.

Comment: No, that should not be required. I just wanted to know the thought process behind it. Cheers !

Comment: @cruisepandey I agree, your answer is good, so I'll try to be more careful in future, sorry.